# Is it possible to cast copper around another metal

Tags: materials, metallurgy, casting

So i have seen these super conductor rods around (which appear to be copper around titanium/niobium).

Now I am wondering (for a maker usecase) if its possible to create something similar by for example casting copper around rods of another material, i.e. iron, nickel, stainless steel, or even just titanium.

What is the science behind this, is it possible to just cast 2 different metals together so they become fused?

Comment: That's pretty much what brazing, soldering, and dip-coating is.  Copper melts at around 1084 degrees C, steel at 1425 - 1520.  I'm not sure how well it'll **stick**, but you could give it a whirl.

Comment: Why not electroplate?  That can be done to about any thickness you desire.

Comment: @TimWescott even to an inch thick?

Answer (score 1):

Looking up superconducting cables on the net , I doubt very much that any casting is involved ( to produce the final cables). The figures show multiple concentric tubes , some tubes to carry the cooling fluid and other tubes are the conductors and copper and insulation... If it was necessary to combine the copper and conductor into a single tube ( in the bundle of tubes) , I expect the conductor wire would be put in the annulus between two copper tubes and cold drawn to make a relatively solid single tube... Titanium has unique properties and doesn't react well to being heated above 800 F; It absorbs N and O from the air which embrittle the Ti ; significant heating requires an atmosphere of argon or helium ( as used in welding Ti).